# Password form style not working in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to change the basic sign in form and did the following style

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Product
from userprofile.models import Customer
from django.forms import TextInput, EmailInput, PasswordInput
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CrateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',]
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',
                'placeholder': 'Exemplu1234',
            }),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',
                'placeholder': 'exemplu@email.com',
            }),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',
            }), 
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',
            }), 
        }
```

Now my problem is that the field for both password did not change while the other two did. How can I make them work?

I tried to reorder the fields but nothing changed.

Comment: try adding just the type as password    `attrs={"type": "password"}` beside changing the form field to `TextInput` or `CharInput`

Answer (score 0):

###### You need to override both password fields like this, I think it should be working...

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Product
from userprofile.models import Customer
from django.forms import TextInput, EmailInput, PasswordInput
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CrateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',]
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',
                'placeholder': 'Exemplu1234',
            }),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'class': 'w-100 p-3 rounded-4 border border-success shadow',
                'placeholder': 'exemplu@email.com',
            }),
            
        }
```